# VBA Concatenating columns from same worksheet in Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble concatenating two columns (variable range) to another column in the same document. Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

```
Function ConcCol(ConVal_1 As String, ConVal_2 As String)
    Range("V30:V500").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ActiveCell
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[5],"" "",RC[6])"
    End With

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Destination), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Function
```

When running the above function, I get the following error:

> Error: Run-time error '1004': AutoFill method of Range class failed

I assume it's something to do with only one cell being activated perhaps? My VBA knowledge is limited

Comment: I don't know where to begin with this one... You are accepting two variables in the function but you never use them. You are trying to select a range, but you haven't told the code what sheet that range is on. Then you use ActiveCell (really bad practice) without activating a cell first.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I haven't included the entire code, as it was quite lengthy and hard to read. Currently two columns are copied from one workbook to another in placeholders, then those placeholder columns are concatenated in that worksheet in Range("V30:V500"), then the placeholders are deleted afterwards. It's not a very well written macro, but I'm just taking it over. Also, not very experienced with VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ConcCol()

Range("V3:V500").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
Cell.Value = "=CONCATENATE(RC[5],"" "",RC[6])"
Next Cell


End Sub
```

I think it'd be easier (if you're going with the selection idea), to just use each cell. I think your with statement doesn't want to loop at all, hence error. This works, a simple solution.

Comment: This works fine, however the concatenate function must be deleted afterwards and replace with the value. So:
`For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[5],"" "",RC[6])"
        Cell.Value = Cell.Value
    Next Cell`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow, Range("V30:V" & Rows.Count))
        .Formula = "=AA" & .Row & "&"" ""&AB" & .Row
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you are a bit confused. How do you plan to run this code? You need to provide more details. Here are three ways of running a vba code:

- User Interface as a User Defined Function (UDF)
- As a Function that is called/used by another VBA code
- AS a macro and user need to run it from the macro list

For your purpose, why doesn't the user use CONCATENANTE function in the sheet and fill down?

Maybe use the Excel array functions?

I cannot post images, need 10 reputations :s

Comment: It's being used as a macro run by a user. The columns change all the time, and users can't be trusted to update the CONCATENATE function in the columns each time